# How to know if Successful/Unsuccessful INSERT (SP) using SQL Server in node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server, axios

I am working on a project using Node JS. I have here an API that returns datasets. I am inserting the values of the datasets on a database. I used axios to call the API. Execution of `INSERT` to database is based on the length of the dataset thrown by the API.

So I loop it using for loop. Then inside the for loop I have a SQL Server `.execute` to run the stored procedure for the `INSERT`. For this I need to know the successful and unsucessful `INSERT` to database.

```
const axios = require('axios').default
const {sql} = require("./config/connection")

var API_URL = '...';

axios.post(API_URL).then(function(response) {
    var success = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < response.data.result["list"].length - 1; i++) {
        
      const request = new sql.Request();
      request.execute('INS_STOREPROC').then(function(recordsets,returnValue,affected) {
        if(recordsets.output.Result < 0) {
            //unsuccessful insert here
          success = -1;
        } else {
            //successful insert here.
          success = 1;
        }
      }).catch(function(err) {
          success = -1000;
      })
      
  }
  if(success > 0) {
    notifySuccess();
  }
  else {
    notifyFail();
  }
})
```

Comment: If the `INSERT` failed, you would get an error; unless you have code to ignore the error but that is a different problem and one you need to address.

Comment: Yes, that's why I added variable to know which data is not inserted so i can be notified.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Your only question is your title is *"How to know if Successful/Unsuccessful INSERT (SP) using SQL Server in node.js[?]"*, and the answer to that is if you got an error.

Comment: the success variable is not updating it is always stayed on 0 even though it is successfully inserted or it has an error

Comment: Though I know nothing of Node.Js (it's the SQL Server tag that has brought me here) is `recordsets.output.Result` meant to be consuming the `RETURN` value of the procedure? `0` denotes success, not `<0`. But that isn't checking for errors anyway. I see no attempt to error handle in the above.

Comment: Please put a breakpoint (or a `console.log`) on `success = -1000;` and confirm whether it ever runs. The `if(success > 0)` line does _not_ run after the `.catch(function(err)` line. You need to be careful with this kind of thing when doing asynchronous processing.

Comment: So what's actually behind the `sql` variable? If you're using the `mssql` library then you'll need to change how you're invoking the [`request.execute()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#execute-procedure-callback) function.